# Java implementation -SSL oneway and twoway handshake switch

Tags: java, ssl

For one client and the server, it that possible to switch one-way and two-way SSL handshakes at runtime?  (Server has to set authentication mode before it runs).

What I come up with is use two ports for one-way and two-way SSL connections separately. Is there a better way to switch them at runtime (using one port)?

**A more complicated case is every client may flip between one-way and two-way schemes. If server chooses one scheme, then any client must use such scheme. How to deal with following scenario? Alice wants one-way while Bob needs two-way.**

Thank you.

Comment: you might as well use SSLEngine instead to have more control over things.

Comment: @bayou.io Why? It's three lines of code with SSLSocket. There is absolutely no necessity to go to the 100x complexity of using SSLEngine and therefore NIO for this problem. 'Might as well' is a pretty cavalier way of expressing a need to change the entire I/O basis of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly. To switch to two-way authentication, do the following at the server end:

- call `SSLSocket.setNeedClientAuth(true)`
- call `SSLSocket.getSession().invalidate()` to invalidate the current session
- then call `getSession().getPeerCertificates()` or friends to (a) perform a new handshake and (b) get the client certificate.

Note that you do have to call `getSession()` twice. Don't try to 'optimize' this away.

**EDIT** Your 'more complicated case' doesn't make sense. It has nothing to do with what the client 'wants' to do. It is a question of whether the *server* wants, or requires, client authentication. Once it has an authentication for a specific client, it doesn't have any need to drop back to non-authentication for that client. And note that the client authentication applies to the entire SSLSession with that client, not just to the current connection. And specifically this statement of yours:

> If server chooses one scheme, then any client must use such scheme.

is completely incorrect. The `needClientAuth` setting is here applied to a single `SSLSocket`, not to every `SSLSocket` for every client.